What symbol or icon can best represent the concept of "original" or "source" content?
I am developing an enterprise chat app that users can create content either from voice speech or a traditional text input. The original source content is transcribed, if it is speech, and then translated to text for receives to read in the language of their choosing.
For instance, Fred speaks French, Elbert speaks English, and Alice speaks Albanian. Fred sends a voice message in French, it is transcribed to French text and then translated to English and Albanian.
The audio, transcribed text, and translated text is all available for the app use and display.
I want best represent to the user which text content is the original. I think denoting with an icon annotation is best, but I can't think of a good symbol for this.

Do a search over at the nounproject.  The words source and original are a kind of abstract concepts, so there's not just going to be one kind of standard symbol everyone will recognise. Note: I've no affiliation with the website or developers.

Consider leaving the word "source" and experiment with chronology: The original post is the first post, if I understand correctly. So study icons for "1st" or "1." and see if it helps, if test users get it.
